# How display the whole documentation of a class instead of only that of only a single method or class with IntelliJ

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to code Java with MacOS. There is a legacy class with many public methods with documentation on probably each of them. I am able to use F1 to display documentation of a single method or a class.

But I would like to see the documentation of all methods of a class in one view (probably scrollable), is it possible? is possible how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA does not offer a "view complete documentation" popup or window.

If you have the source code for the class in question, you can use "Tools" -> "Generate Javadoc" for said class and then view the generated documentation in a browser as usual.